# Iterating through an unlimited number of child objects in a Django queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model that defines a list of categories. Each category can be a child of another category, and it is possible that depth of this list of categories could go on quite a bit.

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    code = UUIDField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    parent_cat = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

Consider for example, a Category for women's clothing. It may have something like the following:

*Women's > Clothing > Dresses > Summer*

That all works fine, but separately I want to build a function that can build a single list containing an extrapolated view of every category in the tree. To do that, I have written the following:

```
    queryset = Category.objects.filter(parent_cat=kwargs['code'])

    all_children = []
    all_children.append(queryset.values())

    for c in queryset:
        children = Category.objects.filter(parent_cat=c.code)
        if children:
            all_children.append(children.values())
    all_children.append(children)
```

I realise this code is probably quite sloppy, I'm still learning!

As you probable realise, this will only give me two levels of child objects.

My question is: What is the most efficient way that I can write this code so that it will find every possible category until it reaches the last object with no more children?

Thanks!!

Comment: Check out [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/) it's a tree traversal app. You might find a solution in their code or alternatively use django-mptt itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using recursion something along the lines of this:
Replace list with the apprpriate data type.

```
def parseQueryset(queryset)


    for x in queryset:
        if isinstancex(x, list):
            parseQueryset(x)
        else:
            #do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Once I knew the term for what I wanted (recursion) I was able to work it out from there! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal - and you can use django-mptt package: https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/overview.html#what-is-modified-preorder-tree-traversal